Don't show the success message by using toastr.js after deleting the category with the sweetalert2.js, just showing the error: toastr is not defined
I want to show a successful delete message by using toastr.js when any user will click on the delete button, first it will show alert, so I use sweetalert2.js, but after confirming delete in sweetalert2.js, it is only deleting the category but it is not showing the success message in toastr.js rather than showing the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: toastr is not defined
In CategoryController:
#region API CALLS

// https://localhost:7230/Admin/Category/getall => to get all the propoerties of Category in json for using in datatable
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
    List<Category> objCategoryList = _unitOfWork.Category.GetAll().ToList();
    return Json(new { data = objCategoryList });
}

[HttpDelete]
public IActionResult Delete(Guid? id)
{
    if (!id.HasValue)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "Invalid ID" });
    }

    var categoryToBeDeleted = _unitOfWork.Category.Get(category => category.Id == id.Value);

    if (categoryToBeDeleted == null)
    {
        TempData["error"] = "Category not found or already deleted.";
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error while deleting" });
    }

    _unitOfWork.Category.Remove(categoryToBeDeleted);
    _unitOfWork.Save();

    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Category deleted successfully" });
}

#endregion

In Index.cshtml:
@model IEnumerable<Category>

<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <h5 class="mb-0">Categories Data</h5>
            <a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Upsert" class="btn btn-primary" style="box-shadow: none" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#categoryModal">
                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> &nbsp;Add Category
            </a>

            <!-- Modal for Create/Update Category -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="categoryModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="categoryModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <form asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Upsert" method="post">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="categoryModalLabel">
                                    @if (TempData["CategoryId"] != null)
                                    {
                                        <span>Edit Category</span>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <span>Add New Category</span>
                                    }
                                </h5>
                                <button type="button" style="box-shadow: none" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <!-- Hidden Field for Id -->
                                <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="@(TempData["CategoryId"] ?? Guid.Empty.ToString())" />


                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="CategoryName" class="form-label fw-bold ms-1">Category Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CategoryName" name="CategoryName"
                                           value="@TempData["CategoryName"]" required placeholder="Category Name" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Dismiss</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
            <table id="tableData" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width: 100%">
                <thead class="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                        <th>S/N</th>
                        <th>Category Name</th>
                        <th>Created At</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/js/category.js"></script>
}

In category.js:
$(function () {
    loadDataTable();
});

var dataTable;

function loadDataTable() {

    dataTable = $('#tableData').DataTable({
        "ajax": { url: '/admin/category/getall' },
        "columns": [
            {
                "data": null, // Serial number column
                "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return meta.row + 1; // Display row index + 1 for serial number
                },
                "width": "10%"
            },
            { data: 'categoryName', "width": "30%" },
            { data: 'createdAt', "width": "25%" },
            //{ data: 'id', "width": "15%" },
            {
                data: 'id',
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <div class="w-75 btn-group" role="group">
                                    <a href="/admin/category/upsert?id=${data}"
                                       class="btn btn-warning text-white me-2" style="box-shadow:none" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#categoryModal">
                                       <i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit
                                    </a>
                                    <a onClick="Delete('/admin/category/delete/${data}')" 
                                       class="btn btn-danger ms-2" style="box-shadow:none">
                                       <i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Delete
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            `
                },
                "width": "35%"
            }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            { "className": "dt-left", "targets": 0 } // Apply left alignment to the serial number column (first column)
        ]
    });
}

function Delete(url) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        icon: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
        cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!"
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'DELETE',
                success: function (data) {
                    /*to reload the page after delete*/
                    dataTable.ajax.reload();
                    //Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: toastr is not defined                          
                    toastr.success(data.message);
                }
            });
        }
    });


}

Error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: toastr is not defined
    at Object.success (category.js:65:21)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2:28327)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2:29072)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2:79901)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2:82355)


You could try this below code. looks like there might be some issue in your original code that you are missing the reference of the js file.
Index.cshtml:
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Category List";
}

<div class="container">
    <h2>Category List</h2>
    <table id="categoryTable" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Created At</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            loadDataTable();
        });

        function loadDataTable() {
            $('#categoryTable').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Category/GetAll",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "id" },
                    { "data": "categoryName" },
                    { "data": "createdAt" },
                    {
                        "data": "id",
                        "render": function (data) {
                            return `<a onclick="Delete('/Category/Delete/${data}')" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>`;
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        }

        function Delete(url) {
            Swal.fire({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                icon: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!"
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: "DELETE",
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.success) {
                                $('#categoryTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                                toastr.success(data.message);
                            } else {
                                toastr.error(data.message);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}

CategoryController.cs:
using CategoryApp.DataAccess.Repository;
using CategoryApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace CategoryApp.Controllers
{
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IRepository<Category> _categoryRepository;

        public CategoryController(IRepository<Category> categoryRepository)
        {
            _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            var categories = _categoryRepository.GetAll();
            return Json(new { data = categories });
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public IActionResult Delete(Guid? id)
        {
            if (!id.HasValue)
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "Invalid ID" });

            var category = _categoryRepository.Get(c => c.Id == id.Value);
            if (category == null)
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "Category not found" });

            _categoryRepository.Remove(category);
            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Category deleted successfully" });
        }
    }

}



